# Divisor of Product

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

If you have three natural numbers a, b and c.

How can you prove that for (b*c), if a does not divide b and it does not divide c, then it also does not divide (b*c)?

Comment: You can't. $4 \nmid 6$ and $4 \nmid 10$, but $4 \mid 60$.

Comment: ok. Now let's add that all three numbers are prime numbers. Would the statement then be true and if yes why?

Comment: It suffices to require that $a$ is prime. Depending on context, that can be essentially the definition of prime, or Euclid's lemma.

Comment: What if b and c are prime, how can you prove that a, also prime, does not divide the product of b and c?

Comment: What is the definition of a prime you're using?

Comment: 2,3 ,5 , 7 ,...